# Why doesn't it return the user from the database by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I use ORM Sequelize(Postgres). I wrote a code that should return user data by user id, but either it just doesn't return anything, or it says "Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed.".

```
async findOne(req,res) {
    try {
        const {id} = req.body;
        console.log(id);
        const user = await User.findOne({where: id})
        return res.json({user});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

router.post('/getOne', userController.findOne);
```

Comment: try `await User.findOne({ id })` or `await User.findOne({where: { id } })`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an object notation in order to indicate the condition `id=:id`:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({where: { id: id } })
// OR 
const user = await User.findOne({where: { id } })
```